# DateFormatter return different time in iOS 14.2 and iOS 16.4

Tags: ios, swift, dateformatter

I tried to get the date and time from Timestamp.  when I see it in iOS 16+ simulator it shows 04.46 PM whereas in iOS 14.2 it shows 16.47. Is there anything im doing wrong here?

Timestamp value: **1700661033**
Date format: **"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"**
Code Used:

```
        let timeinterval: TimeInterval = (timeStamp as NSString).doubleValue
        let dateFromServer = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeinterval)
        let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
        dateFormater.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        return dateFormater.string(from: dateFromServer as Date)
```

Comment: What's the time zone and why are you using `NSDate` in Swift?

Comment: Please update your question with the actual output that you get. A date format of `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss` is not going to give strings like `04:46 PM` or `16.47`. Where's the date and the seconds? You also need to tell us what timezone and locale are being used in the two cases.

Comment: And tell us what the purpose of this string constructed from the date. Is it for some [user-visible representation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter#1680045), i.e., a string to be shown in the UI? Or is it for some [fixed format representation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter#2528261), such as a log, persistent storage, etc.?

Comment: Sory for Not giving enough details in my question. But i found the issue and fixed it with vadian's answer. The issue is simulator and real device have different locale. that why it shows different time. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all please stop using `NS` classes if there is a native equivalent.

To get a reliable result you have to specify a fixed locale either generic `en_US_POSIX` or your preferred locale.

```
let timeinterval = TimeInterval(timeStamp) ?? 0.0
let dateFromServer = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeinterval)
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
return dateFormatter.string(from: dateFromServer)
```

And the output depends also on the time zone of the device.

Comment: All good advice but it doesn't explain the particular issue described in the question which is that the format is woking correctly  in iOS 14.2 but not in recent versions.

Comment: @JeremyP When the locale is different on the simulators the results can be different. The .46/.47 difference is likely the [*is floating math broken*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) issue.

Comment: @vadian Thanks for your info. I found that in simulator the locale is US and time formate is 12 hours. where as in device it is different. A Simple thing i didn't notice.